# Extracting field from cell array of structure in matlab

Tags: matlab, struct, extract

I have a cell array (let's say size 10) where each cell is a structure with the same fields. Let's say they all have a field name x.

Is there a way to retreive in a vector the value of the field x for all the structure in the cell array? I would expect the function to return a vector of size 10 with in position 1, the value of the field x of the structure in cell 1 etc etc...

EDIT 1:

The structure in the cell array have 1 field which is the same for all but some others which are different.

Comment: Why are your structures in a cell array rather than a struct array? Can you give us a [mcve] with sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code creates a cell array of structures, and extracts field 'x' of each structure to a vector v.

```
%create a cell array of structures
s1.a = 'hello';
s1.x = 1;
s2.a = 'world';
s2.x = 2;
c{1} = s1;
c{2} = s2;
v = zeros(1,2);

%extract to vector
for idx=1:size(c,2)
    v(1,idx) = c{idx}.x;
end
```

Comment: Please update your answer to include details & explanation to your code and why it answers @Tulkkas question

Comment: Added, thanks @thiago-belem for requesting the clarification.

Comment: thx, i actually did that but was wondering if there was an efficient way or a matlab function to do it without the for loop?

Comment: @Tulkkas: this is the same loop that would be executed if using `cellfun`, this one could be faster because there is no function handle involved. Time the different options to see which one is the more efficient. Don’t dismiss a solution just because it has a loop, loops are fast in modern MATLAB versions. If you want more efficient code, don’t use a cell array of structs. :)

Answer (score 2):

First convert your cell array of structures, `c`, (with identical field names in the same order) to a structure array:

```
c = cell2mat(c)
```

Then, depending on the data types and sizes of the elements of the field, you may be able to use

```
[c.x]
```

to extract your vector of field `x` values in the "standard" way.

It is also possible that you can skip the conversion step and use `cellfun(@(e)e.x, c)` to do the extraction in one go.

Comment: Comment for OP: the output of `cell2mat` is what you should be using instead of your cell array of structs. It is more efficient (memory wise) and more convenient to use.

Comment: yes that would have worked but i think i have not been clear in something, the structure have all one field which is the same but also field which are different. For this reason this solution would not work.

Comment: That your cell structures have varying fields was indeed not clear originally. In this case use the `cellfun`.  You may have to add the `'UniformOutput',false` parameter setting and wrap the output in `cell2mat`.

Comment: @Tulkkas: the question says “each cell is a structure with the same fields”. Please reword that because now you’re saying this is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have

```
c = {s1, s2, s3, ...., sn};
```

where common field is 'field_1', then you have two options

Use [cell2mat](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html).

```
cc = cell2mat(c); % which converts your cell array of structs into an array of structs

value = [cc.field_1]; % if values are number
```

or

```
value = {cc.field_1}; % if values are characters, for example
```

Another option is to use [cellfun](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html).

If the field values are characters, you should set "UniformOutput" to "false"

```
value = cellfun(@(x) x.field_1, c, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

The first option is better. Also, try to avoid using cell/cellfun/arrayfun whenever you can, vectors are way faster and even a plain for loop is more effecient